# Does $2^n-1$ divide $1+2^{2i}$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $2^n-1$ be a prime number. If $1<i<n$, I need to prove that $2^n-1$ does not divide $1+2^{{2i}}$. Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first sentence is a bit unclear. Is this a hypothesis on $n$ ("Let $n$ be a prime number such that $2^n-1$ is prime")? Note that if $n$ is prime, $2^n-1$ need not be prime (e.g, $n=11$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following proves more than you want.

**Lemma**.  If $n>1$ is odd and $m=2^n-1$ and $i$ is a positive integer then $m\not\mid 1+2^{2i}$.

**Proof**.  If $m\mid 1+2^{2i}$ then modulo $m$ we have
$$2^{2i}\equiv-1\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2^{2in}\equiv(-1)^n\quad\Rightarrow\quad
  (2^n)^{2i}\equiv-1\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1\equiv-1$$
which is not true.

It is also easy to check that the conclusion is true for $n=2$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove more generally that if $n$ is any integer greater than $2$, then $2^n-1$ does not divide $2^m+1$ for any $m$.

If $n\gt2$, it's clearly the case that $2^n-1$ does not divide $2^m+1$ for $m\lt n$, since $2^n-1\gt2^m+1$.

Now consider the *smallest* $m$ such that $2^n-1$ divides $2^m+1$.  Then $2^n-1$ also divides $2^m+1+2^n-1=2^n(2^{m-n}+1)$, which contradicts the minimality of $m$.  Thus no such $m$ exists.

For $n=2$, it's easy to see that $3\mid2^m+1$ if and only if $m$ is odd.